# LACP to Fix Switch Bottleneck?

Tags: switch, ieee-802.1ax, dell

I have a bottleneck affecting traffic. There are 4 switches with each of them running a line to the next to provide internet. I haven't played around with LACP LAG too much and am wondering if the setup in this diagram would work. I am wondering if this would help my bottleneck between the switches.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setup is totally valid, provided all devices support LACP LAG.

Two things though:

1. The network design is not very good, neither for reliability nor from the performance/efficiency perspective. Basically, don't chain but build a tree. If possible, connect the top three switches to the bottom one directly (or even the firewall), shortening forwarding paths, removing dependencies, and removing the bottleneck from the interconnects.
2. Note that aggregating links does not work like a single interface with the aggregated speed. Instead, each member switch uses an algorithm to select a physical link for each frame, so that similar frames always use the same link. Depending on the switch algorithm, the criteria can be source/destination MAC addresses, IP addresses, or IP addresses and TCP/UDP port numbers.

   So basically, the more flows run across a LAG trunk, the more likely it is that they distribute evenly across the physical links. Few flows are not likely to distribute well unless you fine tune the mentioned criteria.

If changing the topology isn't possible and the bottleneck at the bottom switch is hard to remove, using multiple VLANs with MSTP may be an alternative. Grouping the VLANs into several MSTP instances that you can then run over their dedicated interconnects allows you to guarantee bandwidth for the topmost switch which isn't (easily) possible with simple LAG trunks. If this is feasible depends on your workloads and their distribution across the switches.

Comment: If I were to use the bottom switch to bring in the internet from the firewall, could I distribute it to the other 3 switches using SFP to increase the bandwidth between them?

Comment: SFP as a fiber interface? The interface type increase bandwidth, it's all about the speed or bandwidth of the interfaces. If you worry about the distances between the switches then yes, fiber will cover much larger distances than twisted pair (10GBASE-SR runs over 400 m of OM4, or 10GBASE-LR over at least 10 km of OS1).

Comment: Basically if I bridged my firewall interfaces as one network then run a line from each switch to the firewall I would eliminate the chain and the bottleneck it is causing, correct?

Comment: Yes, that would give a star or tree topology with the firewall as the center or root of the tree. Two things to pay attention to: a) the FW might have to be configured as root brigde with the lowest priority of all bridges/switches involved b) switch-to-switch traffic would necessarily have to flow through the Firewall's bridging feature, which might turn out to be your next bottleneck.

Comment: We recently purchased a Watchguard T55 and I see the bridge feature to combine  the various interfaces. Is this the root bridge you mean?

Comment: Marc was referring to *root* as the network core (as opposed to the root of a *logical* spanning tree built by STP - you don't want STP unless you follow the multiple-instance MSTP approach).

Comment: well - that depends a bit. A switch is essentially just a many-port-bridge, typically with hardware ASICs doing the bridging/forwarding "at wire speed" and the populating of the switch's own CAM table (the table containing information about which MAC address is beyond which switch port). Bridging can also be done with a set of classic NICs (usually less than on a switch) and software on a CPU (and used to be done like that in early years of networking). I cannot tell if the Watchguard T55 internally has ASICs or runs the bridging in software, hence the risk of a bottleneck...

Comment: ... when you use the Firewall's bridging feature and place it as the center point of a star or root of a tree topology. I would rather follow Zac67's advice and build a tree topology with the switches, and connect the Firewall to the root of the tree.

Comment: I did redo the networking to have 3 switches going into 1 main switch and that going to the firewall. Still seeing a bottleneck between the switches since only one line is running from the firewall to the main switch.

Comment: You can still LAG the firewall link....